# Почему бот в ТГ не отвечает?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Почему бот не отвечает на 'id' и 'Hello'?))

```
@bot.message_handler()
def get_user_text(message):
    if message == 'Hello':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'И тебе привет')
    elif message == 'id':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Твой ID: {message.from_user.id}')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_user_text(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'hello':
        #код
    elif message.text.lower() == 'id':
        #код
```

`.lower()` нужен, чтобы ты не мучился с кодом и бот делал все буквы маленькими.

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста:)